# Meaning of a Talmud statement about acceptable casualties of war

Tags: army-military-war, politics-government

The Talmud says:

> Shmuel... said: A government that allows one-sixth to die [by going to war] is not punished. [Shevuot 35b]

I don't understand what this means.  That a ruler is allowed to risk the lives of one-sixth of his own population to win a war, but no more than a sixth?  What if more is required to secure victory?  Should he refuse to go to war to defend the country against aggression?

Comment: You discussed here - https://images.shulcloud.com/618/uploads/PDFs/Divrei_Torah/thejewishviewofciviliancasualtiesinwar.pdf :-)

Comment: I don't understand the 1/6.  I didn't answer my own question.

Comment: Tosafos says it's talking about מלחמת הרשות.

Comment: In the absence of a Sanhedrin, who determines if it's a מלחמת הרשות?

Comment: "_Shmuel... said: A government that allows one-sixth to die [by going to war] is not punished. [Shevuot 35b]_" Where did you get that abridged translation from? The text says "דאמר שמואל מלכותא **דקטלא** חד משיתא **בעלמא** לא מיענשא", the William Davidson Edition's translation ([used by Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shevuot.35b.17?lang=bi&vside=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English|en&with=Translation%20Open&lang2=en)) has "_but that which Shmuel says: A monarchy **that kills** one of_ [every] _six_ [individuals] _**in the world** is not punished_ [for doing so]", ...

Comment: ... and [the English Soncino translation of Talmud](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Shevuoth.pdf) (PDF) has "_but then what of
Samuel who said: A government **which kills** only one out of six is not punished_".